# Computing the Jacobi symbol

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, quadratic-residues, jacobi-symbol

I have been asked to compute $\left(\frac{77}{257}\right)$ **specifically using Jacobi symbols**, showing all working. I have done the following:

$\left(\frac{77}{257}\right) =\left(\frac{257}{77}\right)$

=$\left(\frac{26}{77}\right)$ reducing $257 \bmod77$

=$\left(\frac{2}{77}\right)$$\left(\frac{13}{77}\right)$

Then here is where I'm not sure if what I have done is correct:

$(-1)\left(\frac{13}{77}\right)$ since $2$ is a quadratic non residue $\bmod77$? (Can I do this or is there a different way?

=$-\left(\frac{77}{13}\right)$ by flipping

=$-\left(\frac{12}{13}\right)$

=$-\left(\frac{2}{13}\right)^2$$\left(\frac{3}{13}\right)$

=$-\left(\frac{3}{13}\right)$

=$-\left(\frac{13}{3}\right)$

=$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$

=$-(1)$ since $1$ is a quadratic residue $\bmod3$

=$-1$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200134/solving-a-congruence-with-high-numbers-and-computing-the-legendre-symbol/2200158#2200158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use multiplicativity, and the Legendre symbol, since $257$ is prime.
Note that $257\equiv 1 \bmod 4$, and $7\equiv 11\equiv 3\bmod 4$. So we have
$$
\left(\frac{77}{257}\right)=\left(\frac{7}{257}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{11}{257}\right) = \left(\frac{257}{7}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{257}{11}\right)
= \left(\frac{5}{7}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{2^2}{11}\right)= \left(\frac{7}{5}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)=-1.
$$

Comment: I'm not required to show the quickest simplest way but I am asked to _specifically_ use Jacobi symbols and show my working for it so would this count?

Comment: But you are required to justify each step. For example, why is $2$ a quadratic non-residue modulo $77$? If you use multiplicativity, justifications are easier. And the Legendre symbol is an Jacobi symbol, just in a special case.

Comment: That part was a bit of a guess and why I asked the question in the first place, for help with that step. I am asked not to factor the question in the first instance as I am required to demonstrate my understanding of the Jacobi symbol. I know since $p$ is prime Legendre is much simpler but this is not what is being tested so is it possible to go about it my way but legally justifying that $\left(\frac{2}{77}\right)$ is $-1$ or something similar?

Comment: It follows from $8.$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol), because $77\equiv 5 \bmod 8$.

Answer (score 0):

Why not first decompose $\;77=7\cdot11\;$ ? I think it is much simpler:

$$\left(\frac{77}{257}\right)=\left(\frac7{257}\right)\left(\frac{11}{257}\right)$$

and now:

$$\left(\frac7{257}\right)=\left(\frac{257}7\right)=\left(\frac{5}7\right)=-1$$

and also

$$\left(\frac{11}{257}\right)=\left(\frac{257}{11}\right)=\left(\frac{4}{11}\right)=1$$

Comment: I'm not required to show the quickest simplest way but I am asked to _specifically_ use Jacobi symbols and show my working for it so would this count?

Comment: Yes, it would. In both last lines I used the Gauss' Quadratic Reciprocity.

Comment: Is my method still correct?

Comment: @harry55 Not sure: why is $\;\binom 2{77}=-1\;$ ?? What do you mean "by flipping"? This is a rather important theorem and *not always* you can just "flip": at least one of the prime factors involved must be $\;1\pmod4\;$ ...

Comment: That was the part I didn't know, it was a bit of a guess and why I asked the question in the first place, for help with that step. Yes by flipping I meant no sign change by quadratic reciprocity since $77\equiv 1\bmod4$. I am asked not to factor the question in the first instance as I am required to demonstrate my understanding of the Jacobi symbol. I know since $p$ is prime Legendre is much simpler but this is not what is being tested so is it possible to go about it my way but legally justifying that $\left(\frac{2}{77}\right)$ is $-1$ or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Harry in this case the question "use reciprocity to compute (77/257)" and "use Jakobi to compute (77/257)" can be answered in a single answer as shown above because in both cases factorizing 77 = 11*7 is the only way to simplify the symbol. You can't factor out some powers of 2 without factoring any further as usually shown in notes that want to differentiate Legendre from the more general Jacobi. So my guess is that the answer is valid for both cases