# Calculate Legendre symbol

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

When i calculate the legendre symbol for (101/1739), i end up with (2/27)*(5/27) in the middle of the calculation.

I understand how to calculate (5/27), but how do i calculate (2/27). This would have been easy if 27 was a prime but what to do when the denominator is not a prime

Comment: $(2/27)=(2/3)^3=-1$.

Comment: These symbols are called *Jacobi symbols*. For an example, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201040/computing-the-jacobi-symbol).

Comment: Thanks so you dont care about the nominator when you take the power of 3? and then calculate the Quadratic residue of 2/3?

Answer (score 0):

There is noo need to refer to Jacobi symbols here, because we have
$$
\left( \frac{101}{1739}\right)=\left( \frac{1739}{101}\right)
=\left( \frac{22}{101}\right)=\left( \frac{2}{101}\right)\cdot \left( \frac{11}{101}\right)=(-1)\cdot (-1)=1.
$$